# React TS shared styled component props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

What is the right way to let typescript know about props in shared component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react'

export const Input = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'>>(({ err, ...rest }, ref) => {
  return <StyledInput {...rest} ref={ref} />
})

const StyledInput = styled.input`
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px ${({ err, theme }) => (err ? theme.badColor : theme.primaryColor)};
`
```

First issue:

> Property 'err' does not exist on type
>   'Pick,
>   HTMLInputElement>, "form" | "style" | "title" | "pattern" | "key" |
>   "accept" | "alt" | "autoComplete" | ... 276 more ... |
>   "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ThemeProps<...>'

Second issue: 
theme is of type any, but have an interface in provider:
[image]

Third issue:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an type for your styled-components props:

```
type StyledInputProps = {
  err?: string
}

const StyledInput = styled.input<StyledInputProps>`
  // your styles...
`;
```

For your theme you have to create your own theme type. Example:

```
type ThemeType = {
  colors: {
    primary: string,
  }
};

const theme: ThemeType = {
  colors: {
    primary: '#F47829',
  }
};

const App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    // ...
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

Documentation: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript.

To pass your error into your 'Input'-component you have to create one more type for that one (alternatively you can use the same type if all props are the same):

```
type InputProps = {
  err?: string
};

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = forwardRef(({ ...rest }, ref) => {
    return <StyledInput {...rest} ref={ref} />
});
```

Or using the type as the second type parameter for `forwardRef`:

```
const Input = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(({ ...rest }, ref) 
  => <StyledInput {...rest} ref={ref} />);
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if i want to get err from props too? {err, ...rest}

Comment: export const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'>>(
  ({ err, ...rest }, ref) => {
    return <StyledInput {...rest} ref={ref} />
  }
)

Not working :(

Comment: I think it's better to create another question.

Comment: Yeah possibly. When removing the generics from your `forwardRef` it should work however, like in my last edit

Comment: Here is question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59033592/react-ts-get-prop-for-shared-component