# React TS get prop for shared component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

How to let typescript know about err type?

```
type InputProps = {
  err?: boolean
}

export const Input = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'>>(({ err, ...rest }, ref) => {
  // some use for err here
  return <StyledInput {...rest} ref={ref} />
})


const StyledInput = styled.input<InputProps>`
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px ${({ err, theme }) => (err ? theme.badColor : theme.primaryColor)};
`
```

Error is:

> Property 'err' does not exist on type
>   'PropsWithChildren,
>   HTMLInputElement>, "form" | "style" | "title" | "pattern" | "key" |
>   "accept" | "alt" | "autoComplete" | ... 276 more ... |
>   "onTransitionEndCapture">>'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `InputProps`-type as your second generic argument:

```
export const Input = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(({ err, ...rest }, ref) => {
  return <StyledInput {...rest} ref={ref} />
});
```

Comment: It's works too, what is the use for  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'> than :/

Comment: Yeah I honestly don't know either. Couldn't find any docs for it and have never used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, found the answer myself, you just need to add & InputProps:

```
type InputProps = {
  err?: boolean
}

export const Input = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'> & InputProps>(({ err, ...rest }, ref) => {
  // some use for err here
  return <StyledInput {...rest} ref={ref} />
})


const StyledInput = styled.input<InputProps>`
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px ${({ err, theme }) => (err ? theme.badColor : theme.primaryColor)};
`
```